# Definition of symmetry of the open ball in a normed space.

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that every ball in a normed space is a convex set symmetric with respect to the center of the ball.
I have problem with defining symmetry.

Let $X$ be a normed space. And $B_r(a) \subset X$, where $B_r(a)= \{x \in X \mid \|a-x\| < r\}$.
$B_r(a)$ is symmetric with respect to $a$ means that $\forall x, y \in B_r(a), x \neq y : \|x-y\| = \|a-x\| + \|y-a\|.$

Is this the definition of symmetry?

Comment: Symmetry should mean that if $a-\delta\in B_r(a)$, then $a+\delta\in B_r(a)$.

Comment: @Michael Burr, thank you for your answer. I'm sorry for being absent. Do I understand right that one should consider $\delta \in B_r(a)$ ?

Comment: No.  Think of $\delta$ as a small value and $B_r(a)$ as a small ball near $a$.  If $a$ is large, then $a+\delta$ is also large.  If $b\in B_r(a)$, then $\|a-b\|$ is small, but $\|b\|$ might not be small.